# Getting data out of SAS/IML

Tags: sas

I have the following module, as an example, in IML:

```
start multiply (x,y);
    product = x*y;
    return product;
finish multiply;
```

Which I call with:

```
RUN multiply(2,100); /* outputs 200 */
```

What I want to know is very simple, how can I assign this as a new variable?  In PHP I could do:

```
function multiply($x,$y){
    $product = $x*$y;
    return $product;
}
```

Then do:

```
$newvar = multiply(2,100);
```

I need this functionality in SAS.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that since SAS passes by reference we can pass what we want the output variable as an input parameter of our module.  So we can write:

```
start multiply (x,y,z);
    product = x*y;
    z = product;
finish multiply;
```

Which I call with:

```
run multiply(2,100,z);
print z;
```

Passing by reference, efficient but risky...

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your original question is to assign the return value to the matrix:
Instead of

```
 RUN multiply(2,100); /* WRONG */
```

you want

```
 product = multiply(2,100);
```